# Wordpress Pagination, Change Destination

Tags: wordpress

is it possible to change the pagination in wordpress from:
https://schoblatt.de/page/2
to:
https://schoblatt.de/page/2#content

i found: _after_page_number and testet this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_page_word' );
function my_custom_page_word() {
  global $wp_rewrite;  // Get the global wordpress rewrite-rules/settings

  // Change the pagination property which sets the wordpress pagination slug.
  $wp_rewrite->pagination_after_page_number = "#Content";  //where new-slug is the slug you want to use ;)
} ?>
```

But it don't work, i have no experience in php.

Comment: Where did you find this method? `pagination_after_page_number`

Comment: here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

Comment: Hi Volker.  That's not how you use that argument, which needs to be passed in an array for the function paginate_links() - Your pagination function appears in your theme, on the page templates where pagination is in use.  Typically the index.php of your theme/child theme, or other archive type of page.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [paginate_links](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) function to create your pagination, it has the `add_fragment` parameter which is "A string to append to each link."

Example:

```
$args = [
    'add_fragment' => '#content',
];

?>
<nav class="pagination"><?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?></nav>
<?php
```